# Laravel gives different result for mysql query from value saved in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 .

I am trying to save urls in my sql database as following :

```
$table->string('url')->nullable();
```

The saving works perfectly but when i try to retrieve the value,its a bit different from whats saved.

If i save `abcd.com/ab` , the query result gives `abcd.com\/ab`. That is an extra `\`.
Has anyone experienced similar issue? Please guide me.

Code for my  mysql query :

```
$site = DB::table('websites')->where('id','=',1)->select('url')->get();
```

I am new here so if the question has some issues,please let me know. Thanks for reading.

**Update**

I think i am getting closer to the real issue here.When i try

```
dd($site);
```

it gives correct value.
But when i do

```
return $site;
```

it gives this problem.
Can you explain this to me?

Comment: I think the form that is posting the get is urlencoding the data and therefore the extra \ is added.  You will have to urldecode the variable before saving it.

Comment: If you directly query (via workbench or phpmyadmin) the DB what do you see? The output you're indicating is on a blade? in that case try {!! !!} instead of {{ }}

Comment: @Chris i tried what you said,but didn't work. I think laravel is doing something to it in the query part.

Comment: @RoccoMilluzzo In phpmyadmin,the SQL query gives result as it should. No,i am not using blade here.Just trying to get an array using the query.

Comment: Check if you have magic quotes enabled and disable it if needed. What happens now?

Comment: @Fuzzyma i searched about magic quotes. I am using wamp for localhost which has php version 5.5.12. Magic quotes was deprecated before this version. Anyway i tried adding 'magic_quotes_gpc = off' in the php.ini file. The problem still exists. :(